# FFmpeg how to convert a 32bit FLAC at 384kbps to 24bit at 192kbps?

Tags: ffmpeg, flac

Is it possible to do that with ffmpeg? I've noticed that there is no 24-bit listed when using the: `ffmpeg -sample_fmts` command in the Linux terminal:

```
name   depth
u8        8 
s16      16 
s32      32 
flt      32 
dbl      64 
u8p       8 
s16p     16 
s32p     32 
fltp     32 
dblp     64 
s64      64 
s64p     64
```

I think the Kbps can be specified with something like `-arg-ffmpeg 44100` even though I'm not sure what is the value for 192kbps.

I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Don't know if it is of any help, but https://usage.toolstud.io/docs/ffmpeg/usage/sample_fmts/ says "s32 is also used for 24 bits audio". I suppose it then depends on the encoder, which would use padding to store 24 bits of information in 32 bits.

Comment: Mind you, [Flacon](https://flacon.github.io/) will easily do that for you, just not from the command line.

Comment: Jos- I tried Flacon but I have a wavepack and it says it cannot recognize the format. This splitter written in Golang https://git.sr.ht/~ft/unflac handles any kind of bit rate and format but it relies on ffmpeg and I need to specify those arguments.

Comment: I'm going to try this `unflac -arg-ffmpeg -sample_fmt -arg-ffmpeg s32 -arg-ffmpeg -ar -arg-ffmpeg 192000 file.cue`

Comment: The `unflac` seems to work fine. It generated a file which shows this when checked with the `file` utility: `output-file.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 24 bit, stereo, 192 kHz, 42176000 samples`

Comment: Please post your answer, so others may benefit from it.